# Android замена Activity при сохранении нижнего меню

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, activity

Добрый день. Я только начинаю знакомиться с андроид-разработкой и вот возник один вопрос. Делаю приложение с нижней навигацией (BottomNavigationView), в общем принцип работы понятен, но сколько я не искал, не нашел, как заменять текущий активити и сохранять положение нижнего меню.
К примеру, есть приложение с тремя вкладками, которые переключаются снизу: новости, профиль и настройки. Как на каждой вкладке вызывать отдельное активити с отдельными элементами?

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_news:
                ...
            case R.id.menu_profile:
                ...
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                ...
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: `BottomNavigationView` предназначен для переключения контента внутри одной активити. Например, с помощью `BottomNavigationView` можно переключать фрагменты в контексте одной активити.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте ViewPager и вот сюда передавайте

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_news:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        case R.id.menu_profile:
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        case R.id.menu_settings:
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
    }
```

Только тут будут фрагменты, а не активити